# Recognizing the collapse of WCF connection

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF client performing some functions.

This function takes several minutes on the WCF server, but server is for example unexpectedly terminated.

How to detect this problem before connection timeout?

I have to have it in order of minutes and I'd like to find out this problem immediately, as in the classic TCP communication.

For example I can see in debug that my client have immediately some handled exceptions such

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

..so internally the client is aware that immediately, but my function is frozen until the timeout expires.

I tried Faulted event, but it is not raised.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't. WCF 'knows' the connection is lost after that timeout period.

You can try to set the timeouts lower (specifically the `OpenTimeout` and the `SendTimeout`), but that might affect other parts of your software.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx):

> SendTimeout – used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole process of sending a message, including receiving a reply message for a request/reply service operation. This timeout also applies when sending reply messages from a callback contract method.

Comment: I cannot change SendTimeout due to application functionality,but InactivityTimeout seems to help. It can be low

Comment: Okay. WCF has a lot of functions to make this work exactly the way you want to, so just try to set the metrics different and look if it gives the expected behavior. Need more help?